# SQL, getting a specific piece of data and not just a random piece

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.name AS NAME, p.photo AS photo, MIN(p.price) AS minprice, COUNT(p.id) AS productcount
FROM blocks b, typesproducts tp, products p
WHERE (tp.typeid = b.typeid OR tp.typeid IN (SELECT id FROM types WHERE parent = b.typeid)) 
AND tp.productid = p.id AND p.active = 1 AND b.active = 1
AND p.id IN (SELECT id FROM products WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY price))
```

It works perfectly fine.

Only issue is that the photo contains a random photo from the products table.

What I would like to get is the photo that matches the cheapest product, i.e. the product that matches the row where the MIN(p.price) column is fetched.

Anyone know how to update the query so I get the right photo?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to calculate the `MIN(price)` in a sub-query, then match against that

Comment: You sure that query works well?  "and order by" is not valid sql.

Comment: You are right Dan, I have fix it now. The AND was a leftover because I removed a 2nd where clause before I asked the question.

Comment: Could you give a little background on other table like the "Blocks" table, "Types" table and the TypesProduct table because other table like Products seems self-explanatory. And what is by the way the common key/column between blocks and products table and/or then blocks and typesproducts?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but looks like you're looking for something like this

```
SELECT *
  FROM products 
 WHERE price = (SELECT MIN(price) FROM products WHERE active = 1)
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8de99/2)**

Comment: I think he wants data in other tables besides products.

Comment: Yes, but what I need is to somehow mix it into the existing query.